# Sending / receiving SMS in Windows 8 / 8.1 via mobile broadband modem

Tags: windows-8, sms

Recently I have upgraded my HP Elitebook 840 g1 from Windows 7 pro to Windows 8.1 and it seems there is no official HP solution to send/receive SMS messages using a SIM card in embedded 3G/4G broadband module.

In Windows 7 "HP Connection Manager" handled it perfectly but I didn’t find any valid solution for Windows 8.1

I have tried all the apps in Windows store that matches term "SMS" or "broadband" but all of them use internet to send SMS, not my broadband SIM card. Have also installed "Lenovo Mobile Broadband" but this doesn’t seem to work with my mobile card HP Gobi 4112.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After six months I have finally found an app for sending / receiving SMS in Windows 8.1 and it works well

[Mobile Broadband Toolkit](http://support.black-it.eu/en/products/mobile%20broadband%20sms%20toolkit/index.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick search my self, and found two interesting links which might help you with your problem. One of them does requires programming knowledge, and the other is driver related.

### Programmable Interface

On github there is a repository for Windows Universal App's, which might be useful: See [SMS Send and Receive](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/smssendandreceive), which seems to address the SMS interface of Windows. However the [Microsoft API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sms.aspx) might indicate that only some developers might address this interface. Still it should be worth checking out.

### Update drivers

In [HP-LT4112 Gobi 4G Driver Software](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/HP-LT4112-Gobi-4G-Driver-Software/td-p/5086305) they are discussing replacing the original HP driver with a Win7 driver, and in addition with replacing the HP driver with the 'original' Huawei driver. Both option seems to re-enable the functionality of the HP Connection Manager as I read it. (Especially I would like to dray your attention to the Huawei driver or solution providen by desuitem on page two, as seemingly insightful references)

*Disclaimer:* As I haven't got a broadband modem myself, I haven't been able to test these solutions. I also found reference to a WebToGo product my-mobile-broadband, put half the references came from sites like 'shouldIremoveit' and similar.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Though, I'd need done working software for SMS so developing one is not an option right now. Thought I tried to run through it briefly, don't really have time to work on it now. Another option, replacing the drivers with Win7 I have tried as advised but HP Connection Manager doesn't seem to have a  problem with drivers but generally with Win8 system. It doesn't even allow me to install HP Connection Manager to that system. If I install it in compatibility mode it simply doesn't work well, crashes the computer and etc. :(

Comment: Don't know about the installation issue of the manager, but the driver update s tuff mentions some options regarding removing an erroneous USB part/driver which affects the overall system installation. Good luck!

Comment: Hm... Not sure if you understood what I'm looking for. I need a software to send / receive SMS. The drivers and the connection works just perfect.

Comment: I understood the part about sending and receiving, but I thought the connection manager was capable of doing that.

Comment: That's true, but in Win7, in Win8 it doesn't work. At all. It'a not drivers of broadband modem, it just doesn't want to run. Installation is also difficult because it can be only installed in compatibility mode of Win7. But after that it doesn't work.